# How to properly use Dependency Injection in Backend in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor-service that needs a specific "LocalStorage"-service injected. It is done this way:

```
 public class UserApi : IUserApi
    {
        private readonly LocalStorage _localStorage;

        public UserApi(LocalStorage localStorage)
        {
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        }
...
}
```

"LocalStorage" is injected within the Startup.cs (`ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddStorage();
```

(I think it is safe to assume that this works as it should)

I also added my own service with the following line:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserApi, UserApi>();
```

On the razor-page I inject my Service:

```
@inject IUserApi UserApi
```

and access a function there:

```
  private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        if (UserApi.Login( _loginUser.Mail, _loginUser.Password, out string error, out Guid? guid))
        {
            // DoMagic
        }
    }
```

When I try to start my application I receive the following error:

> System.AggregateException
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: BlazorFood.IUserApi Lifetime: Singleton
>   ImplementationType: BlazorFood.UserApi': Cannot consume scoped service
>   'Cloudcrate.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Storage.LocalStorage' from
>   singleton 'BlazorFood.IUserApi'.
>
> Inner Exception 2: InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped
>   service 'Cloudcrate.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Storage.LocalStorage'
>   from singleton 'BlazorFood.IUserApi'

When I remove the AddSingleton-line from `ConfigureServices` I can start my application but retrieve an error when trying to access the razor-page containing the IUserApi-Injection:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
>   'UserApi' on type 'BlazorFood.Pages.admin.Login'. There is no
>   registered service of type 'BlazorFood.IUserApi'

What has to be done to inject my services properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the error message

> Cannot consume scoped service 'Cloudcrate.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Storage.LocalStorage' from singleton 'BlazorFood.IUserApi'

as also indicated from the docs

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Don't make your service singleton when registering it and that should fix the issue

```
services.AddScoped<IUserApi, UserApi>();
```