# How to consume Blazored.LocalStorage inside a .cs class instead a Blazor page?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I saw many examples working in this fashion, but this is not working for me. Any help ?

**Program.cs**

```
...
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using TestFullPage.Classes;

namespace TestFullPage
{
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
        builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Session>();
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
}
```

**Session.cs**

```
...
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

namespace TestFullPage.Classes
{
public class Session
{
    [Inject]
    public ILocalStorageService LocalStorage { get; set; }
    public void updateLocalStorage()
    {
        LocalStorage.SetItemAsync("test", "123");
    }
}
}
```

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject Session sesssion

<button @onclick="() =>Write()">Write to LocalStorage</button>

@code {
public void Write() {
    sesssion.updateLocalStorage();
}

}
```

*Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance ---> LocalStorage.SetItemAsync("test", "123");*

Comment: your code work just fine in my machine can you post the complete code of your component and the caller of 'updateLocalStorage '? also any reason to use the class session as a singleton ?

Comment: Well..I didn't put all the original code to not keep the thread heavy and hard to understand, but this class has a lot of functions that's requires to be a singleTon. Is this working for you even in a SingleTon class ? I will update later for you the call...Need to create a better boiler plate for this...because I've a component calling this method. but bear with me ! thanks !

Comment: @yasseros, just updated the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the class 'Session' as a 'component class' which is not the case
replace it by this and it should works :

```
 public class Session
    {
        protected readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

        public Session(ILocalStorageService LocalStorage)
        {
            _localStorage = LocalStorage; 

        }

        public void updateLocalStorage()
        {
            _localStorage.SetItemAsync("test", "123");
        }
    }
```

You need to change 'Session' from singleton to scooped refer to this thread :
[How to properly use Dependency Injection in Backend in Blazor Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834207/how-to-properly-use-dependency-injection-in-backend-in-blazor-server)

Comment: U sure ? because...this is not a Blazer Server...it's wasm...Will work anyway ?

Comment: why shouldn't it work ? what part exactly ?

Comment: It's because you sent me a link "How to properly use Dependency Injection in Backend in Blazor Server?" - but nevermind ! the point is: Now it works !